# How do you change the tooltip text of an HTML title element?

Tags: html, browser

If I mouse over the tab of a page in a web browser, a tooltip appears showing that page's full title. I would like to change that tooltip; e.g.

```
<title title="Some other text">Name of the page</title>
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: on which event would you like to change it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, not possible.**

You can't change the tooltip of the page tab to be different than the content of the `<title>` element.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution to update `title` as tooltip of `title` tag in `head`

Comment: That's not what I asked. I know how to change the title, it's the tooltip that goes with it I want to change.

Comment: Brother i did a lot research but unfortunately i found out there is no solution for updating title of title tag.