# Browser Tab Title text and Hover text should be different

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, razor

I want to have my browser title text and hover text should be different but it seems unachievable from my end.

```
$('title').text('2020/00640');
$('title').tooltip.text('2020/00640 - Edit Advertisement Planning Consent');
```

It should be look like this.

[image]

Comment: [tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/) is a good and easy to use JavaScript library for tooltips.

Comment: @Tyler2P I want to change my browser tab title tooltip seems it won't work for me.

Comment: according to the accepted answer here (with no reference to any source, although) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55725663/how-do-you-change-the-tooltip-text-of-an-html-title-element it's not possible